# ASCX can't access Property in VB CodeBehind

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, user-controls, ascx

ASCX

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" Inherits="ViewFlyout" AutoEventWireup="false"
    Explicit="True" CodeBehind="ViewFlyout.ascx.vb" %>

   <%= DialogTitle %>

   <div id="flyout" runat="server" style="display: none;" class="flyout" /></div>

   <%= flyout.ClientID %>
```

ASCX.VB

```
Partial Class ViewFlyout
    Inherits Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase
    'Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

   Public ReadOnly Property DialogTitle() As String
      Get
         return "Title Message"
      End Get
   End Property

...etc..
```

Throws this error, in the ASCX page.

> 'DialogTitle' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

The server DIV is accessible, but the property in the code behind is not...

I can't change the class's inheritance to System.Web.UI.UserControl, because all of our custom code breaks.

I've tried changing the ASCX to use CodeFile instead of CodeBehind, but that just generates even more errors, and the original error is still there as well.

---

- This is a Web Application, running .NET Framework 4.0.
- I've been doing a 'Build Solution' after every change to verify its
  not just need recompiled.
- I can access static variables by doing ViewFlyout.StaticProperty

Comment: Does `Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase` inherit from `System.Web.UI.UserControl`?

Comment: It does not.  But even when I Inherit that, instead of PortalModuleBase, the error persists.

Comment: Are you using a web application project, or a website project?

Comment: @ekad web application.  .NET Framework 4.